# Is there a way to get response in json format for Azure Storage Account Queue when Querying from Postman

Tags: azure-storage-queues, azure-storage-account

I created an Azure Storage Account and then a Queue Resource as follows.

[image: Azure Storage Account Queue]

[image: Azure Storage Account Queue Details]

And I have some messages inside of it as follows.

[image: Azure Storage Account Queue Details with Messages]

Now I am able to query with Postman as follows.

[image: Querying Azure Storage Account Queue with Postman]

As you can see, the response is in xml. **Is there a way I can get that in json format?**

Changing that xml in the drop down to json is not helping me.

[image: Querying Azure Storage Account Queue with Postman in json format]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to get the response in JSON format. Azure Storage Queue REST API only returns data in XML format at least as of version number 2020-10-02 (latest version at the time of providing this answer).